# Find out associated div

Tags: php, html, phpstorm

I know that is a really dumb question but I wonder if there is a way, either with PhpStorm tools or with a browser interface to find, to which `<div>` tags its associated the end of tags.

Thanks if you have any tips, because I got much divs in some PHP's echo here and I'm lost.

By the way, I have my code like this.

```php
if (isset($city_name) || (isset($longitude) && isset($latitude)) || isset($country_code)) {
    echo '<div class="row align-items-center">';
    echo '<div class="city_informations col-7 border border-primary">';

    if (isset($city_name)) echo '<div class="row"><div class="col font-weight-bolder"><img src="img/geo-alt.svg"/> ' . strtoupper($city_name) . '</div></div>';
    if (isset($country_code)) echo '<div class="row"><div class="col font-weight-bold"><img src="https://flagcdn.com/16x12/' . strtolower($country_code) . '.png"> ' . $country_code . '</div></div>';

    if (isset($longitude)) echo '<div class="row"><div class="col"><img src="img/globe2.svg"/> <span class="font-weight-bold">Long.</span>  ' . round($longitude, 2) . " &nbsp&nbsp <span class='font-weight-bold'>Lat.</span> " . round($latitude, 2) . '</div></div>';
    if (isset($timezone)) echo '<div class="row"><div class="col"><img src="img/clock.svg"/> <span class="font-weight-bold">' . strtolower(ltrim(date('g:i A', (time() + 3600 * (int)$diff_time)))) . '</span> (' . $timezone . ')</div></div>';

    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: I believe almost all editors have such capabilities, but when dealing with HTML directly (not within a PHP string). You might want to consider outputting HTML directly instead of echoing it.

Comment: Yes I should've precised it, my problem occurs because I have some if/else swich that are creating div.

Comment: Did you try `Ctrl+Alt+L`? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/reformat-and-rearrange-code.html#reformat_file

Comment: Yes but since my div are in IF statement + ECHO, it indents only php, not the html.

Comment: Would probably work better, if you did not echo all of this, but wrote actual HTML, with PHP parts in between only where needed. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

Comment: Might be true, but I have a lot of isset, if and switch case to collect API's datas, so I think writing it you're way would not work or would be even longer than I already have.

Comment: Such code is a good example why you should use proper templating languages ;) How should any IDE be able to check for such conditions?

Comment: What do you mean by a templating language ? Is bootstrap one ?

Comment: No, Bootstrap is a CSS framework. "Templating language" has been given incorrectly by me, as these are not languages - what I've meant are projects like Twig, Blade, even Smarty, that help you to seperate PHP code from HTML markup

Comment: Ok or like Symfony which is a framework using Twig project right ? 
Well the response is because I currently don't have the choice to use them or not.

Comment: You are free to use Twig without Symfony

Comment: PhpStorm is extremely unlikely to help here for you code (printing short HTML strings using PHP). Instead separate HTML (template) and PHP code (data processing logic).

Comment: **The idea is:** 1) you prepare all the data in your PHP (no HTML/CSS here at all; only PHP: querying DB / another API etc) 2) when all data is collected, call a function to render your template (e.g. proper template language or even a simple `include_once` will do) and pass all data there. 3) In a template file you will have HTML with inserts of PHP (or whatever template engine you will be using: PHP itself/Twig/Smarty/Blade/whatever) -- any editor will be much more useful in such scenario (and PhpStorm can link closing tag to the opening -- check in a plain HTML file for that)

Comment: This way (HTML file with inserts of templating engine instructions) it is much more easier to edit the HTML template: e.g. update 6 months later when you already may forget how it's done. Plus this job can be done by another person: one person does PHP, another does HTML -- they work separately in separate files so much less interference / mistakes when overwriting someone else's changes. This way you can even have a different "theme": the PHP (data collecting) code is the same just a different template is called etc.

Comment: OK, thanks for the key. I will take a look at templates. Which one do you advice me ? (the simplest to begin if possible)

Comment: @Kiji_T 1) Simplest? PHP itself (no new things to learn; just get the idea of how to separate the stuff). 2) But I would suggest Twig (easy to use in any project): https://twig.symfony.com/ . 3) Just do some googling, e.g. [Twig vs Blade](https://www.google.com/search?q=blade+template+vs+twig)

Comment: well, thanks for you're time LazyOne. I atleast found which div was missing but I'll try include twig template to my project. But here come a last question.

Can I use twig template only on some files or do I have to use it on my whole project?

Comment: @Kiji_T It's a library so use it whenever you want. It's like making some API requests using cURL, some other requests using Guzzle library and in some other cases using `file_get_contents()`. Ideally you should stick to a single method for consistency .. but you can always mix it if it better suits your needs here or you transitioning from one to another.

Answer (score 2):

PhpStorm is able to auto-detect languages inside strings and will offer syntax highlighting and some amount of code intelligence. However, it will not consider HTML inside string literals as part of the document structure. You can verify that with a code fragment like:

```
<div id="test1">
    <span></span>
</div>
<?php
echo '<div id="test2">
    <span></span>
</div>';
?>
<div id="test3">
    <span></span>
</div>
```

The "Structure" side pane will only reflect the two DIVs that aren't part of PHP strings:

[image: Structure/ HTML]

This is how far the feature goes. If you need advanced HTML logic, you'd better off writing literal HTML, in which case you could use the [**Move Caret to Matching Brace** action](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/navigating-to-braces.html).

Answer (score -1):

For the coders who faces the same issue, I found a solution for that :

I display the page source code on my bowser and I copy it into a html formatter like [this one](https://www.freeformatter.com/html-formatter.html).

Then I can easily see which div is opened and not closed, without all the PHP echo conditions etc.

Thanks anyway !

Comment: Sorry to say that, but this sounds like a horrible idea. Why not structure your application in a way that your IDE supports you best? This would be way faster than running your application in all possible combinations of if/else branches

Comment: I'm building my page depending on user choice so I need much if(isset) echo